# How can I implement onclick for objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have the following javascript function which creates a new row with different cells including button as the cell item type. So how can I implement `onClick` of the button functionality here?

My Code:

```
var propertyCell = row.insertCell(1);  
    var propertyName = document.createElement("input");  
    propertyName.type = "text";  
    propertyName.size = "6";  
    propertyName.id = "pName"+rowCount;  

    //alert(propertyName.size);  
    propertyCell.appendChild(propertyName);  
var image1Cell = row.insertCell(6);  
    var image1 = document.createElement("input");  
    image1.type = "button";  
    image1.value = "Camera";  
    image1.size = "6";  
    image1.id = "image1"+rowCount;  
    //image1.onclick = function(){sdfkvk(dh,sdd)}  

    image1Cell.appendChild(image1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the following code:

```
image1.onclick = function (){alert(document.getElementById("pName"+rowCount).value)};
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the element of the textfield using document.getElementById as the rowcount is the same as the button's value you can get the number by doing a string split. Then I just alert the value, but once you have the value you can do what you like.

```
  image1.onclick = function () { 
      alert(document.getElementById("pName" + this.id.split('e1')[1]).value); 
  };
```

Comment: this.id.split('e1')[1] should return the rowcount number from image1.id, as {this} would point to the button.